# UPDATE n records for each user

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to update n oldest orders per each user. For now I use following code to update 1 oldest record per user, but can't figure out how to update n records...

```
UPDATE orders
                INNER JOIN (
                    SELECT id, MIN(created) AS created
                    FROM orders 
                    WHERE status="queue" AND type="order"
                    GROUP BY user_id
                ) m ON orders.id = m.id
            SET orders.status = "process",
                orders.lock_id ="somehash"
```

I found anserw:

```
set @num := 0, @type := "";

UPDATE orders INNER JOIN(

SELECT id, user_id, created, row_number FROM (
   SELECT id, user_id, created,
      @num := if(@type = user_id, @num + 1, 1) AS row_number,
      @type := user_id AS dummy
  FROM orders
  WHERE status = "queue"
  ORDER BY user_id, created asc ) AS grouped_orders 
WHERE grouped_orders.row_number <= 2

) m ON orders.id = m.id SET orders.status = "process", orders.lock_id = "somehash";
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this will perform astonishingly, but without `ROW_NUMBER()` or other Window functions, and without using loops (even worse than this) the operation becomes more complicated:

```
UPDATE  Orders
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  o1.ID
            FROM    Orders o1
                    LEFT JOIN Orders o2
                        ON o2.User_ID = o1.User_ID
                        AND o2.CreatedDate < o1.CreatedDate
            GROUP BY o1.ID
            HAVING  COUNT(*) < 3
        ) o
            ON orders.ID = o.ID
SET     Status = 1;
```

The `n` in this case is the `3` in the `HAVING` Clause. This works fine if you have a small amount of data per User_ID. IF you have thousands of rows for each the query will soon become fairly slow and cumbersome.

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07464/6)**

Answer (score 1):

Check out how to use [limit](http://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/sql_limit.php) and [order by](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) in your query. These will help you get the n oldest records for each user.

Then you will just have to update as you did for each of these entries as you did for one.

You might have to use a query similar to this:

```
update table set WHAT_YOU_WANT_TO_SET
where table.id in (select id, etc from other_table USING_LIMIT_AND_ORDER_BY)
```